# extract lines with a specific column value with awk command

Tags: awk, filter

I would like to extract all lines starting with a 1/1 **in "12345" column** and put the lines in a new file (-> Newfile.vcf.gz) leaving the first file.vcf.gz intact by using awk command. My file is a file.vcf.gz, please tell me if i need to convert it to something else first.

E.g.

```
#CHROM      POS         ALT     12345   
1           345632      T       0/1:4,4:8:99:105,0,106
4           032184      C       1/1:46,9:55:99:99,0,1222
6           843290      A       0/1:67,20:87:99:336,0,1641
```

expected result

```
4           032184      C       1/1:46,9:55:99:99,0,1222
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk you can use regular expressions. `/^1\/1/` will match if column 4 starts with `1/1`:

```
zcat file.vcf.gz | awk '$4 ~ /^1\/1/ {print}' | gzip -c > new.vcf.gz
```

But if `/` only can occur in column 4 why not just use `grep`?

```
zgrep "1/1" file.vcf.gz | gzip  -c > new.vcf.gz
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, yours is based on the same awk treatment but was more complete.

Comment: Would be better as `gunzip < file.vcf.gz` instead of `zcat < file.vcf.gz` as on some systems, `zcat` only deals with `.Z` (`compress`-compressed) files (same for `gunzip < file | grep` vs `zgrep`). Note that `-c` is not needed when `gzip` is not passed any file argument (but does not harm. Same for `{print}` which is the default action in `awk`).

Comment: Note that `grep "1/1"` would match on `21/1` and `1/12`. The awk one would match on `1/12` as well, the OP may need `/^1\/1:/`

Comment: Oh thanks all! @hschou it worked! What a great first experience of asking for som bioinfo help. Nice! 

So - if I want to combined two and not only have 1/1. 
E.g. if I want all lines with 0/1 OR 1/0 from a column, what would that be?

Comment: @Sanna `grep` allows "OR" via `\|`, so the match pattern would be `1/0\|0/1`. (assuming no other matches as @stéphane-chazelas warned)