# remove lines from a vcf.gz file with awk command

Tags: text-processing, awk

I just asked a question about filtering out lines with a specific value in a specific column.

If I now want to delete lines with a specific value in a specific column. How do I do that?

E.g. delete lines with `1/1` in the column labelled `12345` in the `file.vcf.gz` and put the remaining lines in new file called `newfile.vcf.gz`

E.g.

```
#CHROM      POS         ALT     12345   
1           345632      T       0/1:4,4:8:99:105,0,106
4           032184      C       1/1:46,9:55:99:99,0,1222
6           843290      A       0/1:67,20:87:99:336,0,1641
```

Expected result:

```
1           345632      T       0/1:4,4:8:99:105,0,106
6           843290      A       0/1:67,20:87:99:336,0,1641
```

Comment: Your output does not match the requirements. Deleting `1/1` lines will keep the header line.

Comment: Is the file compressed using `gzip` or with the more specialised [`bgzip` utility](https://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[While this is just the inverse of your last question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325443/extract-lines-with-a-specific-column-value-with-awk-command)

Here is it.

```
zcat file.vcf.gz | awk '$4 !~ /^1\/1/' | gzip -c > new.vcf.gz
```

The `!` makes it match if $4 is not that pattern. However this doesn't remove the header line. To remove the header line you can add `head -n +2` into the pipeline.

```
zcat file.vcf.gz | head -n +2 |awk '$4 !~ /^1\/1/' | gzip -c > new.vcf.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

For deleting lines, I'd prefer `sed`:

```
zcat file.gz | sed ':1/1:d' | gzip -c > new_file.gz
```

Alternatively do an inverse `grep`, ignoring lines that match:

```
zgrep -v '1/1' file.gz | gzip -c > new_file.gz
```

For also deleting the header, make another intermediate `sed` or stripping `tail`, i.e.

```
zcat file.gz | sed -e ':1/1:d' -e '1d'  | gzip -c > new_file.gz
zgrep -v '1/1' file.gz | tail -n +2 | gzip -c > new_file.gz
```

Comment: Note that VCF files are sometimes compressed using `bgzip` rather than with `gzip`: https://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html

Comment: Wouldn't this delete rows that contain `1/1` *anywhere* in the line?

Comment: @RonJohn correct, it does.

Comment: But OP only wants rows removed when `1/1` is in column 4.